# not enter HTTPPOST Action in asp core web api

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-2.1

i create aweb service in `asp core2.2` and send data from client `(angular6)`.

my controller in `Admin` area .

this **Startup :**

```
 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseSignalR(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapHub<CrudRealTime>("/CrudRealTime");
        });
        app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");
        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "areas",
                template: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
            );
        });
    }
```

i use this address for access `Create Roles` Actoin in RoleManager Controller :

`https://localhost:44390/api/role/createrole`

but it not enter in action . when i use this role it work : `https://localhost:44390/api/role/GetRoles` but i dont know whats the problem and how can i solve this .

last time i run the project and it givee data from Client but now it not work . i did not change any things in server code .

how can i solve this problem ????

**RoleAction**

```
 [HttpPost("CreateRole")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> CreateRole([FromBody]RolePostModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            var result = await _roleManag.CreateAsync(new Role(model.description, model.rolelevel, model.name));
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                return Ok(Messagesresx.Success_Add_Role);
            }
            else
            {
                return Content(Messagesresx.Fail_Add_Role_In_DataBase);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Complete your sample and mention the whole controller class with its attributes too.

Comment: What error do you get when trying to POST to `https://localhost:44390/api/role/createrole`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you able to hit CreateRole through Postman? Try it by setting the accept header as application/Json if you are posting in Json.
If it successfully hits then it means either you need to configure the InputFormatter in your startup of WebAPI to accept the format in which you are posting from your angular app, or try changing the format in which you are sending.